# How to replace servlet doPost method with PHP or Python or Perl?

Tags: php, python, servlets, post, http-post

I am uploading a image file on the server using javascript and servlet. My servlet doPost method is as follows.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   System.out.println( " Image is sent to server ");    

    ServletInputStream servletInputStream = request.getInputStream();
    File captureFile = new File("./images/img1.jpg");
    System.out.println(captureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    if(!captureFile.exists()) {
        captureFile.createNewFile();
    } 

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(captureFile);
    int c;
    while((c = servletInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        fileOutputStream.write((char)c);
        //System.out.print((char)c);
    }
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

In javascript I am creating header and body as follows:

```
header = 'POST /File/upload HTTP/1.1\r\n';
body += '[[[BINARY_IMAGE]]]\r\n';
body += '\r\r';
```

Now  I want to replace this servlet code with the PHP. But I am not understanding how will I do it in PHP or Python. Can anybody guide me on this? Even Python or Perl replacement will work for me.